# Some of my HTMLs are not loading CSS file

Tags: html, css, django

I have a main.css file where all my styles are and some of my html files are loading them, but not all of them.
All my html files extends base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2a770f4891.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>{% block title %}E-Learning{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<nav class="nav">

        <label for="check">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" id="sidebar_btn"></i>
        </label>


        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user.first_name != '' or user.last_name != '' %}
        <b class="top-menu" style="font-size:20px; margin-right:5px;"> Hello, {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</b>
        {% else %}
        <b class="top-menu" style="font-size:20px; margin-right:5px;">Hello, {{ user.username }}</b>
        {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="top-menu">Log out</a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu"> Log In </a>
        <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="top-menu">Register </a>
        {% endif %}
    </nav>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <a href="{% url 'subject_new' %}" > <span> Add </span></a>
    </div>

    <main class="content">

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

and for example my register.html extends base.html (with all css files) just fine

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<b>You're already logged in.</b>

{% else %}

  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="register-window">
    {% for field in form %}
       <p class="label_tag"> {{ field.label_tag }} </p>
       {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <br> <small class="help_text">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="login-button">Register</button>
     </div>
  </form>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**but** my subject_detail.html seems to ignore my css file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}



    {% block content %}
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="subjecttitle">{{subject.name}}</div>

<div class="subjectlessons"><p>{{subject.header|safe}}</p></div>
     {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

Also this html file doesn't load my css:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_teacher or user.username == 'admin' %}

<div class="card">
    <h2>Add subject</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ formfile.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
    </div>
{% else %}
<b>You can't do this</b>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am doing this in django, so this is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for teamproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ewmxjw-q3eh=0-+9iq4*$8myvreo8-zg4v+*tkgz5q=+iqg%)q'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'eLearning',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_cleanup',
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'teamproject.urls'

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'eLearning/Templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'teamproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

# LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-pl'

# TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

LOGIN_URL = '/login'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'eLearning.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

# gmail-mail settings
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "elearningteamproject@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'projektzespolowy1'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        "removePlugins": "resize, elementspath",
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'height': 300,
        'width': 600,        
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Font', 'FontSize', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'TextColor', 'BGColor', 'RemoveFormat', 'Blockquote', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar'],
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'SelectAll', 'Find', 'List', 'Preview', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', 'HorizontalRule'],
            [],
            ]
    }         
}
```

Every file extends base.html (I can tell by the header) but some of them ignore CSS file.
If you need more files to try to solve my problem please ask and I will add this to question.
**Things I tried:**
I tried adding `{% load static%}`, `python manage.py collectstati`c, adding `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` at the end of my urls.py

**EDIT:**
For subject_detail.html I tried to add CSS file in the most basic way:

```
{% block title %}E-Learning | Subjects{% endblock %}



    {% block content %}
<head>
    <link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="subjecttitle">{{subject.name}}</div>
<div class="subjectlessons"><p>{{subject.header|safe}}</p></div>
     {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

even without extending base.html and adding

```
<link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but it still doesn't work. I don't know where problem is.

***EDIT 2***
This is my structure:

```
├───eLearning
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───static
│   │   ├───css (here is my main.css)
│   │   └───scripts
│   ├───Templates (here are all my .html files)
│   └───__pycache__
```

***EDIT 3***
This information that I get from cmd:

`"GET /subject_detail/3/static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5079 Not Found: /subject_detail/3/static/css/main.css`

Comment: subject_detail.html  has a lot of problems. You should read over the documentation again.

Comment: @aris I tried to add diffrent things  to make it work, that's why I added for example `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` in subject_detail.html, but when I followed rules it also didn't work. I added one more file that didn't work to compare it. Thank You for your comment.

Comment: Your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` make me think that you are running it on PythonAnywhere. Do you have your static file mapping configured? See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes from your question and add like this in your code it should work.
this is in your `base.html` file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2a770f4891.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>{% block title %}E-Learning{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<nav class="nav">

        <label for="check">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" id="sidebar_btn"></i>
        </label>


        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user.first_name != '' or user.last_name != '' %}
        <b class="top-menu" style="font-size:20px; margin-right:5px;"> Hello, {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</b>
        {% else %}
        <b class="top-menu" style="font-size:20px; margin-right:5px;">Hello, {{ user.username }}</b>
        {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="top-menu">Log out</a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu"> Log In </a>
        <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="top-menu">Register </a>
        {% endif %}
    </nav>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <a href="{% url 'subject_new' %}" > <span> Add </span></a>
    </div>

    <main class="content">

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is in your `subject_detail.html` file

```
{% block content %}
<div class="subjecttitle">{{subject.name}}</div>

<div class="subjectlessons"><p>{{subject.header|safe}}</p></div>
     {% endblock content %}
```

if it is working on your base.html than by doing this it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work, it even didn't load css for html files that loaded it before

Comment: Still no succces, 
replacing `<link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` with things you sugested didn't work, it even didn't load css files to .html files that loaded it before.

Comment: provide your directory structure